# Finding the distance, currency, temperature units etc. for a country (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, localization, iphone-sdk-3.1

During the localization of my app I went through a lot of documentation, somewhere Im sure I read that there is a way to get a set of units that is linked with the locale.

I believe it said something like "units based on cultural..." something.

I would like to display temperature and distance in Fahrenheit and Miles for some countries and Celsius and Kilometers for other countries.

Is there a way to access a list of these units in the iPhone SDK.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `NSLocale` to check the currency unit, <del>but for imperial vs. metric you need to make a list yourself</del>.

Oops. You *can* check for the imperial vs. metric. There is are `NSLocaleMeasurementSystem` and `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` keys.

Comment: Hi Kenny
Thank You! 
Guess I'll give it some more thought to as if it can be justified loading such a list for two small labels :/

Comment: Hi Kenny! Thanks for getting back on this one:) just perfect, I had not yet begun compiling a list of countries vs. measurement system so this came at a perfect time. Thanks again.

Comment: It is actual as simple as: BOOL isMetric = [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];

Answer (score 9):

It is worth mentioning that Apple provides a nice library (MKDistanceFormatter, introduced in iOS 7) to automatically present a CLLocationDistance as the appropriate string for a given user's locale and language.

It does a little fuzzy rounding (e.g. 300ft->350ft->400ft), but does nicely convert between units (e.g. feet -> miles, when appropriate to do so).  Unless you demand really precise values, this class is perfect for returning rough estimates for distances in two lines of code.

```
MKDistanceFormatter *distanceFormatter = [[MKDistanceFormatter alloc] init];
[distanceFormatter setUnitStyle:MKDistanceFormatterUnitStyleAbbreviated]; // Optional
NSString *formattedDistance = [distanceFormatter stringFromDistance:100];
NSLog(@"%@",formattedDistance); // Prints "350 ft"
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDistanceFormatter_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 8):

I just wanted to note, that, as with the release of **iOS8** there will be new `NSFormatters` for at least some of the units you mentioned.

There will be `NSLengthFormatter`, `NSMassFormatter` and `NSEnergyFormatter` which are very easy to use – see this [**iOS8 NSFormatter tutorial**](http://www.ama-dev.com/ios8-nsformatters-nsenergyformatter-nsmassformatter-and-more/). Here is an example using the NSLengthFormatter with swift:

```
let lengthFormatter = NSLengthFormatter()
println(@"Kilometer: %@", lengthFormatter.stringFromValue(1000, unit: .Kilometer))       //Kilometer: 1,000 km
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

1.)

```
import MapKit
```

2.) Since creating formatter is expensive, you better set formatter as a lazy property. By doing so, you can initialize the formatter only when it's necessary and reuse the formatter rather than create a new one.

```
lazy var distanceFormatter: MKDistanceFormatter = {
    var tempDistanceFormatter =  MKDistanceFormatter()
    tempDistanceFormatter.unitStyle = .Abbreviated // .abbreviated in Swift 3

    return tempDistanceFormatter
}()
```

3.)

```
let distanceString = self.distanceFormatter.stringFromDistance(yourDistance)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted this method to String extension. Looks elegant

Swift 4.1 version

```
import MapKit

extension String {
    init(distance: Double ) {
        let mkDistanceFormatter = MKDistanceFormatter()
        mkDistanceFormatter.unitStyle = .abbreviated
        self = mkDistanceFormatter.string(fromDistance: distance)
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let distance = Double(34234.0)
let stringDistance String(distance:distance)
```